# Where can I find the source code of libgio?

Tags: gnome, source

I want to study how its GFileInfo components works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you get `libgio.so`? On most Linux distributions, there's an automatic way of retrieving the source code of a package.

For example, on Debian, Ubuntu and derived distributions, run `dpkg -S` to see what package `libgio.so` belongs to, then `apt-get source` to get the source code of that package. Example (`$` represents my shell prompt; on my system, the gio library is in a file called `libgio-2.0.so`):

```
$ dpkg -S libgio-2.0.so
libglib2.0-dev: /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so
libglib2.0-0: /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
$ apt-get source libglib2.0-0
```

Comment: Right, but you need the corresponding `deb-src` lines in /etc/apt/sources.list for that to work.

Answer (score 4):

The [glib git repository](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio).

Comment: That repository is gone. The current version is in a subdirectory of GLib: https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio

Answer (score 2):

GIO is part of GLib, so just download the latest GLib. The GTK+ project always has a link because it's a dependency of GTK.

http://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php

There's also gio-standalone: http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/sources/gio-standalone/